# Backfilling keyed old data to compressed hypertable

Tags: timescaledb

I have a hypothetical Hypertable `candle` of exchanges and their trading pair data:

```
create_hypertable('candle 'timestamp', create_default_indexes=>FALSE);
```

The `candle` data looks a bit like this, basically a price movement break down by `pair_id` (trading pair) and `exchange_id` (exchange where the trading happens):

```
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 timestamp          | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 pair_id            | integer                     |           | not null | 
 exchange_id        | integer                     |           | not null | 
 open               | double precision            |           | not null | 
 high               | double precision            |           | not null | 
 low                | double precision            |           | not null | 
 close              | double precision            |           | not null | 
 buy_volume         | double precision            |           | not null | 
 sell_volume        | double precision            |           | not null |
```

This table is then fed to continuous aggregates that then provide daily and weekly rolled up values on open, high low and close prices.

I would like to [compress this table](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/compression/). However, the issue is that while I can compress the current data fine, in some point of the future, I need to import data from exchanges that where not in the system by the time of the launch. Basically there will be a lot of inserts to past `timestamp` values with a new `exchange_id`. Even though the most of the `candle` table data is immutable and could be compressed by limiting it by a `timestamp`, if I perform bulk past data load for an `exchange_id` that was not been seen before, it is going to violate this rule.

- What is the best way to handle this situation?
- Can I bulk load data to compressed hypertables safely (my assumption is I cannot)?
- Any workarounds... for example should I have a new column `created_at` for the data insertion date (not the the trading date) that I could use as a compression trigger, instead of the natural date?
- Can the compression condition consider only filtered `exchange_id` columns and I could compress `exchange_id` I know to be safe by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to handle this situation?

I'd consider adopting smaller chunks, so compress and decompress will become faster operations.

> Can I bulk load data to compressed hypertables safely?

Timescale is [in progress](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/2857) with the implementation of this ability.

> Can the compression condition consider only filtered exchange_id columns and I could compress exchange_id I know to be safe by hand?

Maybe try to [add_partition](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/add_dimension/)?